# jQuery append using nth-child instead of first

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm editing a script that was originally like

```
$('.navigation-area:first').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

However the application has since changed and this item needs to be appended to the second .navigation-area. I've tried:

```
$('.navigation-area:nth-child(1)').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

but that didnt work.

Are there any other suggestions to how to do this? I would've assumed the above would work. Is there any particular reason why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.navigation-area:eq(1)').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, it's [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$('.navigation-area:eq(1)').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

or

```
$('.navigation-area').eq(1).append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

EDIT: According to the docs for jQuery's [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

> Note that since JavaScript arrays use *0-based* indexing, these
>   selectors reflect that fact. This is why `$( ".myclass:eq(1)" )` selects
>   the second element in the document with the class myclass, rather than
>   the first. In contrast, `:nth-child(n)` uses *1-based indexing* to conform
>   to the CSS specification.

So, you can also try:

```
$('.navigation-area:nth-child(2)').append('<li>New Item</li>');
```

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks. I'll mark this as answered.